# Microsoft SQL Server - Canceled ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, used space grew. How to reclaim space?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I executed query

```sql
ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

But decided to cancel it before it finished because it took too much time. Used space massively increased and not freed up. Table rows 490M.

How to reclaim free space?

Comment: `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` although if you intend to try this again you may as well leave that space there

Comment: Disk usage grew 800GB. Will it recover automatically when needed?

Comment: A database file doesn't get smaller automatically. You would have to shrink the file, which comes with a wealth of considerations, such as that it will cause fragmentation of the database.

Comment: SELECT file_id,
       name,
       CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS bigint) * 8 / (1024*1024) AS space_used_gb,
       CAST(size AS bigint) * 8 / (1024*1024) AS space_allocated_gb,
       CAST(max_size AS bigint) * 8 / (1024*1024) AS max_file_size_gb
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type_desc IN ('ROWS','LOG');

The difference between SpaceUsed and Size (allocated) is 900GB.
Do you mean this 900GB is still available for future use?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to if you had expanded the file manually, but hadn't written any data yet. Unless you plan to stop adding data to the database and don't plan to try adding constraints again, just leave it. Shrinking it now just so it has to grow again later doesn't accomplish anything. Can you rent out the space temporarily? Give it back to IT so you can request an expansion later? There's nothing you can do with space you free up only to use again. Lots of articles but sometimes headlines are enough. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Comment: Some other thoughts [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17277/1186), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/139969/1186), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158982/1186), [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/95646/1186), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186) (though that's mostly about logs) and, most importantly, [here](https://am2.co/should-i-shrink-my-database/).